# Use of parameters in a echo statement in a batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, parameters, cmd, user-input

I need help with some batch file syntax. In my batch file I have the line:

```
set /p memo=Memorize: %=%
```

Which will allow a user to set some values. Lets say the user writes "hello world".

So now, `memo==hello world`.

And then I save it to a file with the following code:

```
echo //par1//%memo% >> memod.txt
```

Is there any way to make the output look like this?

> //par1//hello //par2// world

i.e.: make the individual words into individual parameters?

Comment: Do not add `SOLVED` to the title. Instead, mark the best answer as accepted

Comment: You may post your own answer and accept it as Best answer, if you think it is better than the rest...

Answer (score 1):

```
set memo=hello world

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%memo%") do echo //par1//%%a //par2//%%b
```

This `for` command split the `%memo%` value in `%%a` and `%%b` parts (tokens=1,2), using space (default value) as separator.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, i just got a tiny bit better at coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo //par1//%memo: =//par2// % >> memod.txt
```

does as you ask - but I'm not sure whether what you've asked is really what you want to do...